# Whats does [position] accomplish?

Tags: java

What does this method accomplish?

```
 URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
```

myRemoteImages is a String list, with 4 different variables. And position is a

```
int position;
```

EDIT: 
  So if there anyway i could take the place of position with possibly something else?

possibly

```
 myRemoteImages{1,2,3,4};?
```

EDIT: i am using this to get the the URI for each image in the cahce...

```
public void getImagesfromCache(){
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter();

    String[] cachImages = myRemoteImages;

    try {   
     URL aURL2 = null;
     aURL2 = new URL(cachImages[position]);
     URI imageCacheUri = null;


     try {
            imageCacheUri = aURL2.toURI();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(new File(new File(this.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "thumbnails"),"" + imageCacheUri.hashCode()).exists()){
            Log.v("FOUND", "Images found in cache! Now being loaded!");
            String cacheFile = this.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir() +"/thumbnails/"+ imageCacheUri.hashCode();
            ImageView i = new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(cacheFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

             i.setImageBitmap(bm);
             putBitmapInDiskCache(imageCacheUri, bm);

             Log.v("Loader", "Image saved to cache");

             ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
              .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainMenu.this));
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As you see where position is used, how could i go about another way to return the URL's to get the images in the cache?

Could i possibly store each URI in a SharePreference and fetch them  in onCreate()??

Comment: you mean a String array (String[]). A list (as you said), although concepts are close, is not at all the same kind of object in java and is not addressed in the same way and has different methods..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates a [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) object, from the url string specified by the element within the array (myRemoteImages) at the specific position.

The following syntax creates a URL object

```
URL aURL = new URL(<a string describing a URL>);
```

The following syntax gets the String value at the specified position

```
myRemoteImages[position]
```

So, to get a URL for each position, you could do

```
URL url1 = new URL(myRemoteImages[0]);
URL url2 = new URL(myRemoteImages[1]);
URL url3 = new URL(myRemoteImages[2]);
URL url4 = new URL(myRemoteImages[3]);
```

It would be far better though to have an array of URLs though. So it would be

```
URL [] urls = new URL[myRemoteImages.length];
for (int i = 0; i < myRemoteImages.length; i++) {
   urls[i] = myRemoteImages[i];
}
```

With this array of URLs, even though you know there are only 4 images, it can be extended easily without having to change any code. Hard coding is VERY bad, and will usually lead to errors in the long run.

Comment: Instead of have myRemoteImages[position]. Is there anyway since i know its only 4 positions, set the positions manually?

Comment: Check out my edit above to give you a better idea of what i am doing.

Comment: How could i make an array of URLs like you stated in your updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that `position` is an int with the value of 3. The code you posted will then look like this when executed:

```
URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[3]);
```

`myRemoteImages[3]` means: give me the third item in the String list `myRemoteImages`. `new URL()` will create a new instance of [URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) with that third item as the *spec* parameter.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know you changed the question. @Codemwnci perfectly explained above, so I upvoted his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are no `list` variables in Java only List objects. This is an array and position is the value of the offset from the beginning of the array.  Arrays are different than lists such as those found in Python and other languages. Arrays are of fixed size and are objects.

Answer (score 0):

`position` is the element in the array (not list) to access. If you have 4 strings then position should be an integer between 0 and 3.

`myRemoteImages[0]` will be the first image, and `myRemoteImages[3]` will be the fourth and last.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `URL` from an element of an array, probably an array of `String` items.

How is `myRemoteImages` declared?

Comment: public   String [] myRemoteImages = {imageUrl,imageUrl2,imageUrl3,imageUrl4};

Answer (score 0):

`myRemoteImages` must be an *array*, not a List.

That is the java syntax for accessing the element of an array at that index.

Comment: Check out my new edit. Gives you a better idea of what i want to accomplish